# How to build a React page/URL into plain HTML, CSS and JS?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have been hired to develop the frontend for an HTML template that will after be sold in a platform. We would normally do the job using PHP, Gulp, Webpack, etc but since I am starting a course on React I would like to use the ability of developing with react components and the routing tools only during the develop stage.

However, I was wondering if you know a way to build single React pages/urls into separate plain HTMLs as well as the plain CSS. I have seen a tool called React-Snap but I cannot get it to do what I want.

Any help would be much appriciated!!!

Thanks

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, you want to create a dynamic site in React and then render the whole thing into a full, static representation of that site in plain HTML/CSS?  If react-snap didn't do what you want, what was the issue?

Comment: Got it, I finally got my head around react-snap. I was just calling the wrong nmp script. Thanks!